# XML Parsing with parseFromString with portuguese characters

Tags: blackberry, cordova, xmlhttprequest

I have a Blackberry app developed using PhoneGap. I am using suds client to call web service. There are some Portuguese character in the webservice XML. I am not able to parse to XMLDoc using the DOMParser.

I am using

```
xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(_xml, "text/xml");
```

The encoding type is UTF-8. Without the Portuguese character, parsing is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

"I am using is UTF-8 encoding type." - this can mean several things, so it is unclear what exactly you do in order to support UTF-8 end-to-end.

E.g. you should check:

- your web service really sends data in UTF-8 (when it converts string chars into bytes to be sent into output stream it should use UTF-8)
- the device code that reads data from web really uses UTF-8 to convert bytes to string _xml

P.S. I'm not familiar with phonegap API so this is just a general plan.